# How to access application through ALB if Route 53 domain has expired?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb, aws-elb

I have a `spring-boot` application deployed on `AWS`. Earlier we were using a domain and associated the `A type` IPv4 to the application load balancer under it's record set.

Every things seems to be working as expected but now recently, we were required to let the domain expire and associate new domain in future but till that time, we want the application to be accessed.

The problem is, am not aware of how to dissociate the domain. I have the load balancer `arn` with me, the security group is set to the correct ip. The `listener` is set to `443`, but every time I hit the `arn`, it doesn't open the app and says `the site can't be reached`.

What is the correct way now? Do I need to have an `Elastic IP` for the `ec2` where my app is running? How can I access this with ALB directly? Do I need to add a listener for port `80` as well?

Please guide.

Note: It's a docker image which is deployed on private ec2 instance.

Comment: An Application Load Balancer does not have a static IP address. You should always reference it via a DNS Name. Is your domain name pointing directly to the EC2 instance or is it pointing to the Load Balancer?

Comment: pointing to the load balancer.

Comment: When you say that you "associated the A type IPv4 to the application load balancer", what IP address are you referring to? It should be a `CNAME` record pointing to the Load Balancer's DNS Name.

Comment: Yes, it is pointing to ALB's DNS only.

Comment: What do you mean by "every time I hit the `arn`"? An ARN is an Amazon Resource Name, which is a unique identifier used within AWS. It is _not_ a URL, so resources cannot be accessed by "hitting an ARN". Feel free to edit your question to provide information and clarify exactly what you are doing, such as fixing the `A` record vs `CNAME` record per the above comments.